# Dart - Linting option to force explicit types

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a linting option for Dart that forces explicit types?
I don't like how if I have an unspecified return type for a function it becomes dynamic, while if I don't specify the type for a variable it properly infers it.

It feels like the inference system is half done. I would rather just have it force everything to have a specified type, even if it is void (in the case of methods).

Is there a linting option for this?

Comment: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/analysis-options, http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure!

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
linter:
  // usual stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, I will be using this. Do you know where I can find a full list of the analyzer options? I'm doing some searches but can't seem to find an exhaustive list.